# if variable contains, output those that do

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a data set in JS, i can point out that a letter is in a string (word from the database) but i can't manage to discard the words that dont contain the letter and just output the words that do contain the letter.

```
data = apple, orange, grape.

user inputs 'p'

if(data contains user input)
{
    output the data that contain the user input.
}
```

// code outputs = 'apple', 'grape'

//orange is discarded because it doesn't contain 'p' (the users input).

Sudo code above, how do i go about doing this?

Comment: You probably also need to loop over the data.

Comment: It would be better if you would show us the actual code instead of pseudo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` loop to iterate over the data, and `indexOf` to test for a match.

```
var data = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape'];
var input = 'p';

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].indexOf(input) != -1) {
        console.log(data[i]);
    }
}
```